# Android adjust width of the ad-mob advertise to 70% of the screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I want to modify the size of the advertise of ad-mob to 70% of the screen as shown in the figure. I tried it, through changing  the layout

[image]

**Layout**

```
 <LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adlinear"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >

    </com.google.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

this XML works fine in large screen but problem with the small screen. In small screen it doesn't show and gives error.

```
02-05 19:21:59.265: E/Ads(11210): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <106, 636>
02-05 19:21:59.266: E/Ads(11210): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <336, 636>
02-05 19:21:59.267: E/Ads(11210): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <106, 636>
02-05 19:21:59.269: E/Ads(11210): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <336, 636>
```

is there any possibility to modify the requirement <480, 75> of advertise??

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `ads:adSize="BANNER"` to `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"` and in the code

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```